# OneSignal PlayerId from android studio webview app

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, onesignal

There's been a lot of talk about this already, but I just found confusion.

I want to send notifications on my android app to a single user.

(I hate android studio, and I'm not that good at java)

I have my website with registration/login, and user id.

The idea is to create a mysql table with my Onesignal userId and playerId, and then send push notifications to a single user via curl.
[image]

I connected oneSignal to my app in android studio.
[image]

(I receive push notification if i send it from onesignal)

I have this code which allows me to save the playerId of OneSignal in my database, but I can only get the playerId from website, not from android app.

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
    <script>
      var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
          appId: "bb1bf59b-fb3b-4906-a0a8-279d5623f9d7"
        });
      });
      
  OneSignal.push(function() {
  
  //playerid salvato in mysql
  OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
  if (isEnabled) {
      // user has subscribed
      OneSignal.getUserId( function(userId) {
          //console.log('player_id of the subscribed user is : ' + userId);
          // Make a POST call to your server with the user ID  
          AjaxOneSignal('onesignal.php', '?uid=<? echo $user_uid; ?>&rand=<? echo time(); ?>&playerid='+userId);      
      });
  }
});
});
</script>
```

How do I get it from android app?

(Sending my userId as a tag to OneSignal would also be fine for me, I just need a quick and easy way that works.

Please help me get out of this stupid nightmare...

(No, i dont want to use firebase, that thing doesn't work, it breaks with every update of a plugin, a module, an sdk, android studio, etc, etc, etc... I wasted three days of my life with that crap without getting anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

As I see you have OneSignal SDK in your application. You can use this method to get playerId

```
OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(new OSSubscriptionObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onOSSubscriptionChanged(OSSubscriptionStateChanges osSubscriptionStateChanges) {
       String playerId = osSubscriptionStateChanges.getFrom().getUserId();
    }
});
```

Here can use `JavascriptInterface`, it allows to call java code from the javascript.

1. When you get `userId` from OneSignal store it in some variable.
2. Then create method like this. In this case I create it in Activity:

   ```
   @JavascriptInterface
   public String getUserId() {
       return userId;
   }
   ```
3. After that you need add JavaScriptInterface to your webview:

   ```
   webView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"OneSignalBridge")
   webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   ```

Here we use `this`, because our method with `JavascriptInterface` annotation located in Activity.

`OneSignalBridge` - is just a random name, you can use any name you want

4. Now you can call this method from javascript code.

   ```
   <script>
     function someFunc(){
         var userId = OneSignalBridge.getUserId();
     }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: And then how i find it in my javascript/php script? javascript -> playerId variable?

Comment: Hello, sorry, can you explain me in which files I have to put each code? https://ibb.co/vjC40Hp

I've imported everything, synced everything, but userId is stuck on red.

Comment: A new error https://ibb.co/2qmZnVH

Comment: @alebal you need to define userId variable and then set to it id that you receive from OneSignal